# Could the email address at the time of a Bounce be frozen into the Mail Bounces report?

Tags: civimail, civireport, bounce

**Mailing Reports > Mail Bounces (CiviCRM 4.7.9)**

If the email address of a contact is updated, earlier **Mail Bounces** show the updated address instead of the address when the bounce occurred. The address that caused the bounce should be frozen into the bounce record at the time it is reported.
The current behaviour is especially inappropriate for an online newsletter where the contact may not have to enter a name. In this case, the Mail Bounces report (view) itself shows the edited email address, not the original, in the first column.
Is anyone else bothered by this?